# How to add parameterized message properties with outputFormat inside tag attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, properties, internationalization, jsf-2.2

How could I add an outputFormat inside a tag attribute?

**Example**

```
...
<p:column headerText="#{msgs.actions}">
    <p:commandButton id="btnDelEspai" icon="fa fa-trash Fs16 White"
                     styleClass="Fright RedButton" iconPos="right"
                     action="#{espaisBean.deleteEspai()}"
                     title="#{msgs.esp_delete}"
                     update="frmEspais:tblEspais frmEspais:error_panel">
        <p:confirm header="#{msgs.delconfirmation}"
                   message="ADD CODE HERE" icon="ui-icon-alert">
        </p:confirm>
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{e}"
                                     target="#{espaisBean.selEspai}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
...
```

**Code to add**

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msgs.esp_delconfirmation_id}" >
    <f:param value="#{e.id}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

Comment: `#{of:format1('one {0}', 'two')}` http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings

Comment: any other option with jsf or primefaces?

Comment: Add a formatting method to a bean and do the formatting there. See also https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.6/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/el/functions/Strings.java#L255

Answer (score 1):

Simply call a method using EL. You could use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) which already has such a method in the [`String` functions](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings):

```
#{of:format1('one {0}', 'two')}
```

or you could create your own method in a bean:

XHTML:

```
#{yourBean.format1('one {0}', 'two')}
```

Bean:

```
public String format1(String pattern, Object param) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    new MessageFormat(pattern, getLocale()).format(param, result, null);
    return result.toString();
}
```